# Fakes stopped working after installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-fakes

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 as a try-out and since then my unit tests that use fakes won't compile anymore, not even on VS 2013. The unit test project targets .net 4.5.

[Msdn](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1049179/after-adding-vs-2015-i-cannot-generate-fakes-on-the-system-assembly) suggest changing the target framework version. The error is gone if I change the targeted framework to 4.6 but I cannot update my project to .net 4.6 as every developer must update at once.

Error that I get:

> The primary reference "mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes" could not be resolved
> because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=4.6
> fraemwork. This is a higher version than the currently targeted
> framework ".NETFramework,Version=4.5".

I've also tried to remove the fakes and recreate them but they do not build, I get errors like this:

> The type or namespace name 'EventDataAttribute' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing'*;

Any fixes for this?

Comment: So far my solution has been to remove all fakes and replace them with RhinoMocks...

Answer (score 14):

You can probably remove the problem classes. If your build output has statements like

```
warning CS0115: 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.Fakes.StubX509Certificate2.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override 
warning CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EventDataAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing'
```

Then it can be removed from mscorlib.fakes or System.fakes files

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Remove FullName="System.Diagnostics.Tracing"/>
    <Remove FullName="System.Text.Encoding"/>
    <Remove FullName="System.Security.Cryptography" />
  </StubGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Now, it may be a bit more nuanced than that.  In order to get it to work, I needed to target the Unit Test project to 4.6 to generate the mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes .dll the first time.  Then I could retarget it back down to 4.5.1.  But, working with the config may be worth a bit of your time as I was able to work around a similar problem.

Here's a [Microsoft problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1049179/after-adding-vs-2015-i-cannot-generate-fakes-on-the-system-assembly#) report which is where I got the workaround.

Comment: Link at end of answer is outdated: *"Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired"*.

Answer (score 0):

I have to mention that besides the solution posted by doobop, which worked for me, also the following lines were required:

```
<Remove FullName="System.FormattableString" />
<Remove FullName="System.IO" />
```